# Broken image on LinkedIn invite feature

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

On Careers 2.0, there is a new LinkedIn-powered invitation feature. When you click on the `select connections` link you are greeted with:

[image: LinkedIn invite page]

Looks like someone on LinkedIn done goofed up and deleted `http://press.linkedin.com/sites/all/themes/presslinkedin/images/LinkedIn_WebLogo_LowResExample.jpg`, it is a 404 response:

```
$ curl -# -o /dev/null -D - http://press.linkedin.com/sites/all/themes/presslinkedin/images/LinkedIn_WebLogo_LowResExample.jpg
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Date: Tue, 13 Nov 2012 11:11:45 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Set-Cookie: NSC_W.HMJEF.MJOLFEJO.80=ffffffff09291f6845525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660;expires=Wed, 14-Nov-2012 11:11:45 GMT;path=/;httponly
```

Comment: Well, think I found a [mirror image](http://i787.photobucket.com/albums/yy159/mpca/LinkedIn_WebLogo_LowResExample.jpg) the devs here can put it in the imgur account and use it instead of depending on external sources. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up, we've fixed this.